# Update MySQL Tables Values from another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have the following tables in `MySQL`

**Agent**

```
Agent     Type
--------------------------
Bob       1,2,3,4
Sam       2,3,4
```

**Type**

```
Type      Name
--------------------------
1         Gold
2         Platinum
3         Silver
4         Supreme
```

My question is how can I update Agent table to look like this by using a `select statement`

```
Agent     Type
-----------------------------------------
Bob       Gold, Platinum, Silver, Supreme
Sam       Platinum, Silver, Supreme
```

Comment: Fix your data model.  Storing ids in strings is a really, really, really bad idea.

Comment: It would not be scalable for long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will split up the array into rows then use group concat to put it back into an array. The downsize of this query is you need to increase the table numbers in case that there are > 5 values in the longest array in agent.type column.

```
SELECT agent, GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY name) 
as type
FROM (
    SELECT
  agent.agent,
  type.name
FROM
  (SELECT 1 as n 
   UNION ALL SELECT 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 
   UNION ALL SELECT 4
   UNION ALL SELECT 5) numbers 
INNER JOIN agent
ON CHAR_LENGTH(agent.type)- 
CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(agent.type, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
INNER JOIN type 
ON type.type = 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(agent.type, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1)
      ) tab
GROUP BY agent
ORDER BY agent;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others above have mentioned you should convert the Agent table so the Type column isn't a comma separated string where you want to have one row per number, so in this example the Agent table would be seven rows long and your queries will be simple e.g.

```
SELECT
A.Agent,
GROUP_CONCAT(T.Name) as Type
FROM Agent AS A
INNER JOIN Type AS T ON T.Type=A.Type
GROUP BY A.Agent
```

Whereas in the current state you could use REPLACE in place of a join:

```
SELECT 
Agent
,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(type,'1','Gold'),'2','Platinum'),'3','Silver'),'4','Supreme') as Type
FROM Agent
```